# What are the dangers of removing a lens while the camera is on?

Tags: lens, equipment-protection, dust, power, changing-lenses

The manual warns that you should turn the camera off to remove the lens, but it doesn't say why.

I suspect this may have to do with dust, but I could imagine there are lots of other reasons. I'm hoping someone can tell me the reason for doing this, so it will help me to never forget :-).

Comment: Which camera are you using? I can't find anything in a Canon DSLR manual which advises turning the camera off to change lenses.

Comment: @Matt Grum: Like many users I've encountered on this site, I have my gear on my profile. I'm using a Nikon D7000. The message is on page 26 of this online manual: http://www.nikonusa.com/pdf/manuals/noprint/D7000_ENnoprint.pdf.

Comment: Hmm seems to be a Nikon thing. What does it say under manual sensor cleaning? Are you supposed to turn the camera off, remove the lens, turn it back on, open the shutter and then clean the sensor?

Comment: Ha, yes! Page 286 of the same manual: turn the camera off, remove lens, turn it back on...

Comment: My guess: Nikon doesn't test for this, so they tell you not to do it.

Comment: @wberry The issue with Nikon is probably due to the risk of damaging a mechanical linkage if it is engaged in an improper position at the time the lens is removed.

Comment: They are being over protective.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

When I get this question from my students, the underlying question is often based on the persistent myth that taking a lens off without first turning off the camera will 'fry' the lens, the camera, or both (depending on who you talk to).

With both Canon and Nikon cameras the leftmost pins on the body (when looking at the camera) are the VBat (6 volt lens power) pins, so when the lens is disengaged and rotated counterclockwise the first thing that happens is that power is removed from the lens. Since none of the other lens contacts sweep over the VBat pin, that scenario is actually physically impossible. Additionally, since the lens power is disengaged from the moment the lens is rotated, the lens is no longer able to pass information back through the communication (dcl and dlc) and clock (dclk) pins. Thus there is very little danger of bad data getting passed between the camera and the lens and somehow 'corrupting' anything unless you really *snap* the rotation of the lens and there "happened" to be communication going on at just the right moment. In any case, simply turning off the camera and turning it back on would clear such an error.

While I have no direct experience with the pin and contact patterns of other brands of SLR/dSLR, I would be very surprised if the others (Sony, Pentax, etc.) did it differently.

Comment: To add further weight to the assumption that they all do this... if they didn't ensure the power was disconnected first, and/or didn't ensure that power didn't get applied to the data pins, there'd be hundreds of thousands of dead lenses/cameras around and product recalls to fix it. That sort of thing wouldn't just *sometimes* kill a lens — power applied to a data connection (which isn't specifically protected for such a circumstance) will kill the electronics almost instantly.

Comment: I like the answer overall. Clearly everyone else does too, so I am going to go ahead and accept this. But do you buy into the dust argument? I also find it strange that says Canon says to do this and Nikon says not to. @Matt Grum seems to think that Nikon is just covering themselves for no real reason.

Comment: By the way, I was wondering if "frying" the lens or camera could happen -- or if this was really just about dust. You guessed right since I'm basically a student :-).

Comment: Thanks! I'm afraid the only comment I can add to the 'dust question' is an anecdotal one... I've been using dSLR cameras for... ohhh... a decade or more now, and have never bothered turning off my camera while changing lenses... In all that time I've never lost a single picture to dust... I'll go one step further- I can't recall ever having had to erase a dust spot in Photoshop. All that seems to indicate (to me at least) that the problem of the charged sensor attracting dust- even if it is completely true- is a very minor problem at best.

Comment: The "charged sensor" argument does have some validity *if the shutter is open*, such as in Live View. Charging the sensor probably won't attract dust particles from outside the light box. But if dust is blown through the mount opening and into the sensor by air currents the charged sensor could cause the dust to be more likely to stick to the front of the sensor stack. And if the air that blew the dust in is also humid, then the moisture could "glue" the dust in place and make it much harder to remove than dry dust.

Comment: And I *have* needed to use dust removal tools in post after changing a lens in very humid environments, especially if shooting at narrower apertures or if using post processing techniques that increase local contrast, such as HDR.

Comment: Nikons do have mechanical linkages between the camera and lens that Canons lack. If those linkages are engaged in a certain way or position when a lens is removed it might increase the risk of damage to the linkage.

Comment: Like the electrical contacts the way the mechanics are designed in the Nikon lenses it is not possible for this to cause a problem.  The most that would happen is the aperture iris would open more while you are removing the lens.  This would actually be do to a reduction of pressure on the linkage.

Comment: @MatthewWhited The aperture position lever is also spring loaded inside the camera. I have seen instances where allowing the lever to pop back suddenly (such as when holding it out and then releasing it) has caused the return spring to become unseated from the attachment point. This requires a near complete disassembly of the camera to reattach the other end of the aperture lever return spring.

Comment: This is ten years old now, but this was linked to on a recent question. On Olympus cameras, pressing the lens release button also cuts power to the lens.

Answer (score 18):

I've been changing lenses with the camera on as long as I've been using DSLRs and I know a lot of other photographers who do the same. If there was a significant risk of causing damage the manufacturers would have had it in the neck by now as so many pros do it.

I suspect this is another case of there being an astronomically small risk, but the camera manufacturers have nothing to lose by telling you to turn the camera off. It's the same as when the airlines tell you to turn off your Nintendo DS during takeoff/landing. You'd severely hope it takes more than a pocket games console to down an airliner, but instead of proving this, it's easier for them to just ban it.

Comment: Nikons do have mechanical linkages between the camera and lens that Canons lack. If those linkages are engaged in a certain way or position when a lens is removed it might increase the risk of damage to the linkage.

Answer (score 12):

The main reason to switch lenses while the camera is off it to avoid exposing the sensor to dust while it is charged as that increases the chances of dust sticking to it. It is really not a big deal but if you want to stack the odds in your favor, you know what to do.

There is probably an infinitely small chance that turning the lens will cause a lens read error since the lens contacts move while the lens is turned to remove it.

Comment: I've often heard the "charged sensor" argument but never seen evidence to back it up and I'm afraid I don't buy it. When the camera is on but not exposing a frame there is nothing going on on the sensor to generate any charge. And if there were the shutter would still be closed and any charge would not be strong enough to attract dust from outside the camera body, about 4cm away. Yes changing lenses could stir up the air inside the camera, but no more (and probably less) than the mirror flipping up while shooting!

Comment: Also with Canons (and assume other brands as well) sensor cleaning is performed with the camera on. The manual advices activating the sensor cleaning function and blowing the sensor to clean it. If the sensor were charged there's no way this would work.

Comment: Matt, I've been wondering about this topic for a while, and while... And would like to find a hard answer. I find that your comments fall short of that, for me, though, particularly in one point: it's entirely possible that a sensor cleaning function would leave the sensor in a different charge state than is normal for when the camera is simply on. I don't know the real story, but your explanation seems contrary to what seems logically plausible to me. If you can back it up with references, please do.

Comment: Also, this answer (a charged sensor attracting dust) is the I've heard most often... Whether it's factual or not, I'd like to know, but it's definitely an answer I've commonly heard (and I haven't heard the "frying the camera or lens" theory, until now.)

Comment: Why does my explanation seem contrary to common sense? Common sense says to me that when the sensor is not doing anything, there's no current flowing through it and thus no charge.

Comment: @matt - Can you here the TV on Mute? I can't but my wife can. I did not believe her at first but I wondered why. It is not exactly the same, but the answer is that it takes time to initialize the sensor. It is better to keep it ready than turn it back on for each picture.

Comment: @Itai Your wife can hear the TV on mute because the amplifier is still trying to amplify the input signal even if the TV is not sending a signal - the noise on the line gets amplified. A camera is not a mains powered device, keeping the sensor powered on all the time seems like a bad idea in a battery powered device. As far as I know the only thing you need to do before shooting is earth the charge from the photosites before opening the shutter, something that is done before any shot anyway...

Comment: @lindes Think about it this way, if the sensor cleaning mode somehow kept the sensor in an uncharged state, why does the camera not keep the sensor in this state all the time, since keeping the sensor uncharged ought to drain the battery less...

Comment: @matt - Guess I was not clear, she can hear the actual conversations/dialog of the show in progress, not a humming noise. I stuck my head against the TV and yes, it still outputs audio on Mute. Honestly, it did surprise me at first but it makes the transition from mute to unmute smoother and quicker. One of my TVs has a 'speaker off' button too and that one outputs a 'jolt' (for lack of a better word) of sound when pressed, I assume from the circuit opening and closing.

Comment: @MattGrum: Are you certain, or are you guessing?  If the former, could you please site a reference or explain exactly why?  I'm admit I'm only guessing (not enough EE training), but imagine that in sensor cleaning mode, a *relatively* high-current but low-voltage constant signal is applied to the sensor, which is also connected through a drain resistor, just to keep it all at a constant and low voltage, versus allowing static charge to exist.  I'm happy to admit I might be way wrong, I just want to know if you're guessing (like me) or know, and if you know, I want more details... please! :)

Comment: I don't know anything for a fact, I'm afraid, just basing my assumptions on the fact the camera is a battery powered device, and quite unlike a TV / PC / amplifier which are designed to be constantly performing a task, and take time to boot up (or warm up/charge caps in the case of amps). All the sensor has to do to prepare to shoot is drain the photosites of any charge built up through heat since the last shot. I highly doubt this charge is enough to attract dust from any distance, especially from outside of the camera body!

Answer (score 6):

I change lenses with the camera on from time to time, but I also always run the dust removal function on the camera afterwards. Now, that may be camera brand specific (Pentax for me), so I don't want to assume it generally applies. The only time I absolutely make sure it is off is when I put a manual lens on because the Pentax SR function will ask for the focal length.

Answer (score 6):

I have never bothered to turn the camera off when switching lenses.

If I ever had any problems like a lens not working properly, it would easily have been fixed by turning the camera off and on again, and it can't have happened many times because I can't recall any incident. Besides, that could just as well have happened if I turned the camera off for switching the lens.

As Matt Grum pointed out that he couldn't find any instruction to turn the camera off in the manual, I checked the camera manuals for my EOS 300 and my EOS 5D mark II, and the procedure for attaching a lens doesn't even mention turning off the camera. I checked the manual for a lens also, and that doesn't mention it either.

I definitely remember reading it somewhere, so it might be there in some manuals, but if there was a good reason for turning the camera off, it would be in every manual, both for cameras and lenses, and it would be hard to miss.

Answer (score 4):

As the comments to the original question indicate, it depends on exactly which camera you are talking about.

Nikon lenses have a mechanical connection for aperture control that is spring loaded at both the camera end and inside the lens that could suffer damage if disconnected while in the wrong position. If the tab on the control lever in the camera is bent it causes incorrect aperture settings that usually result in overexposure (because the tab usually bends up and the lens doesn't stop down as far as the camera tells it to stop down).

Some Nikon cameras also have mechanical connections between camera and lens for auto focus. If the lens is disconnected while the focus screw is moving I would imagine the potential to damage it would be much like you can strip the head of a screw by turning an improperly applied screwdriver.

Canon EOS lenses have no mechanical connections to the camera (other than the mount itself) and there are no warnings against removing lenses while the camera is turned on in Canon *User Manuals*. All control connections between an EOS camera and lens are electronic and the main power supply coming from the camera is the first connection to disengage when the lens is turned to dismount it. The connection is also designed so that the camera's power pin doesn't brush against any of the lens' other pins as the lens is rotated off.

I don't have enough knowledge of manufacturers' systems, other than Nikon and Canon, to comment on them, but if the connection is all electrical it should be safe to remove the lens without turning off the camera. If the connection includes some mechanical linkages it may not be.

Answer (score 2):

I've never bothered to turn off my camera before removing a lens, and so far I haven't broken one because of it. I have had dusty cameras, but I mostly suspect it might cause some electrical glitches somewhere, which is why they want you to turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main reason is to "park" (hard disk terminology) the components.
e.g. VC/IS elements can by their nature move around.
When you power the camera off, those elements are "parked".
I'm pretty certain I've read in manuals/leaflets (yes it's a unsavoury habit I've picked up, I do read manuals..) that come with lenses.

This may also be true with focus elements.

Interestingly [this Nikon Australia NPS article about transporting lenses](https://nps.nikon.com.au/pages/newsupdate.asp?newsid=%7B252626363-149o6mu5r4u-149-5652384161%7D) says that you should turn off VR, while the camera is on if you're going to ship a lens.

Here's the guts of the post:

> When transporting lenses, either by road or air please ensure you do
>   the following:
>
> 1. Ensure both the Front and Rear lens caps are affixed correctly.
> 2. Turn your VR off (where applicable) whilst the lens is still connected to a camera that is powered on, this will ensure the correct
>      locking of the VR mechanism so that it does not move excessively
>      whilst in transit.
> 3. Ensure the lens is well protected, whether in a camera case or if freighting, the correct amount of packing material is used.

Also in some scenarios, with some lenses it is possible that the rear element may protrude slightly (one of the reasons  teleconvertors are not recommended with some lenses)  into the camera body increasing the risk of a knock as it is removed.

Comment: +1 My (US) Nikon manuals say the same thing, with a few more details on stuff that could go wrong. (Though it's not permanent.)

Answer (score 1):

The manual for my camera (a Pentax K100D) states that you should turn the camera off to prevent possible damage to the autofocus motor: if you bump the shutter-release button while changing the lens, it's possible that the now-exposed autofocus drive shaft will catch on something.

Answer (score 0):

My 400mm telephoto works on my D90 ONLY if I put it on with the camera turned "ON". If I connect the lens first and then turn on the camera, I get an error. I would have to pay a couple hundred dollars to have the chip re-flashed to work on the D90 without having to have the camera on first.